# Django .order_by() with .distinct() using postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a `Read` model that is related to an `Article` model. What I would like to do is make a queryset where articles are unique and ordered by `date_added`. Since I'm using postgres, I'd prefer to use the `.distinct()` method and specify the `article` field. Like so:

```
articles = Read.objects.order_by('article', 'date_added').distinct('article')
```

However this doesn't give the desired effect and orders the queryset by the order they were created. I am aware of the note about `.distinct()` and `.order_by()` in Django's documentation, but I don't see that it applies here since the side effect it mentions is there will be duplicates and I'm not seeing that.

```
# To actually sort by date added I end up doing this
articles = sorted(articles, key=lambda x: x.date_added, reverse=True)
```

This executes the entire query before I actually need it and could potentially get very slow if there are lots of records. I've already optimized using `select_related()`.

Is there a better, more efficient, way to create a query with uniqueness of a related model and order_by date?

**UPDATE**
The output would ideally be a queryset of Read instances where their related article is unique in the queryset and only using the Django orm (i.e. sorting in python).

Comment: What version of Django are you running? Passing parameters to `distinct` is only available in 1.4+

Comment: 1.4 and using postgres, it works

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better, more efficient, way to create a query with uniqueness of a related model and order_by date?

Possibily. It's hard to say without the full picture, but my assumption is that you are using `Read` to track which articles have and have not been read, and probably tying this to `User` instance to determine if a particular user has read an article or not. If that's the case, your approach is flawed. Instead, you should do something like:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    read_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='read_articles')
```

Then, to get a particular user's read articles, you can just do:

```
user_instance.read_articles.order_by('date_added')
```

That takes the need to use `distinct` out of the equation, since there will not be any duplicates now.

**UPDATE**

To get all articles that are read by at least one user:

```
Article.objects.filter(read_by__isnull=False)
```

Or, if you want to set a threshold for popularity, you can use annotations:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Article.objects.annotate(read_count=Count('read_by')).filter(read_count__gte=10)
```

Which would give you only articles that have been read by at least 10 users.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This particular query is actually for following what multiple users you are following are reading. I left out the other filter which does this. I need this for aggregating across multiple users so in that case it seems more efficient to query the Read model rather than the Article model. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ChrisPratt you have a typo in the first query of your update: ready_by

Comment: Your answer works fine if you are looking for the Article. I'm interested in the Read instances though. So the output should be a queryset of Read instances whose articles are unique. I'm not sure the ORM will let me do that without some sort of sorting in python instead of the django orm.

Comment: "read" is a *status*, not an instance, i.e., there's no such thing as a "read". There's no query you can run with it as a separate model, that you can't run (more efficiently, in fact) as a status attribute on `Article`. My last code sample gives you all "read" articles, so I'm not sure what you're missing here, but if you need anything else, give me the specifics and I'll show you a query for that as well.

Comment: Much appreciated. Looks like this is a deeper issue with the choices I'm making about the database schema. Going to think more about the implications. If this were a     ManyToMany field on the     Article model relating to a     User object it would not have the information I need (i.e. what time was it read). If I were to do a ManyToMany relating to a Read instance I'm still in the same conundrum.

Comment: You can add additional info to the relationship. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships