# Combining order_by and distinct in django

Tags: django, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

Hi all,

I read quite a bit about it, I can understand that such an implementation is missing, but I can't get why I can't, with Django, emulate the behaviour ob a SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT[...]) ORDER BY.

I know that PostgreSQL does not support a DISTINCT ON without having the column in the ORDER BY clause. But I can reach the result I want by doing the ORDER BY on the subselect of the DISTINCT. And I would like to do same in Django, as performance in this case no issue is. But Django QuerySets are (too) lazy.

I would have loved to be able to run this :

```
b = Backup.objects.filter(state__iexact='up').distinct('md5_checksum').order_by('-create_date', '-title')
```

Or at least this:

```
b = Backup.objects.filter(state__iexact='up').distinct('md5_checksum')
if b.count() > 6:
    b = b.order_by('-create_date', '-title')
```

But unfortunately, even with the try to force the execution of the first query through the count() call, it tries to do the distinct and the order_by in the same query, which is failing.

Therefore, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230124/django-order-by-with-distinct-using-postgres), I have to go back to python sorting to do the same:

```
b = sorted(b, key=lambda x: (x.create_date, x.title), reverse=True)
```

If anybody had a more elegant solution, a way to force Django to commit the first SELECT DISTINCT, I would be please to have it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In the `order_by` method, you might try adding `'md5_checksum'` as the first parameter. That might help it order correctly, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: If you put 'md5_checksum' as a first parameter of the order_by method, it will be ordered by it at first, which is not what I am looking for. I want the files ordered by create_date and title, but for which I just want one distinct md5_checksum entry.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use QuerySet's `raw` method to run your own SQL that works for you here.

Comment: Yep, this is the other thing I thought about, but I find a bit dirty, not much more elegant than the one using python list sorting... OK my query is not very common, but I neither think it is so exceptional.

Comment: For posterity -- it usually has a faster runtime than python list sorting, so it's usually slightly more elegant.